# Create a PCS12-file with python cryptography for a chain of certificates

Tags: python, cryptography, keystore, pkcs#12

There is this method of the package cryptography:

```
cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12.serialize_key_and_certificates(name, key, cert, cas, encryption_algorithm)
```

That enables to create a p12-file with a certificate/key pair.

1.
Now I have a chain of certificates [certs] that I like to put into a p12-keystore and I have no clue how to do this? Neither a concatenation of the certificate bytes nor the byte-string of the PEM worked.

2.
If this is been done. Is there a way to add via Python additional certificate/key-pairs to an existing keystore. I like to avoid using the keytool-cli tool.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for pushing a chain of certificates to a keystore is to create a pem-str and then load this string as a pem-certificate:

```
    pem_str=''
    for crt in crts: 
        pem_str += crt.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM).decode('ascii')
    crt = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_str.encode('ascii'))
    p12 = pkcs12.serialize_key_and_certificates((args.CN).encode('ascii'), pkey, crt, None, 
                                                BestAvailableEncryption(args.P12pwd.encode('ascii')))
```

I am not sure if there is a more direct way? Still open is the 2nd part of my question.